# How can I test game center (multipleyr) on single IOS device

Tags: iphone, ipad, game-center

How Can i test game center (multiplyer) on single iPad device. Please give me idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible.  You cannot run the multiplayer functionality of GameCenter within the simulator (as documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW16).

I myself just bought a 2nd iOS device for this very reason.  On the plus side, having two devices allows you to try out other multiplayer games from both sides, to see how things work.

If you have an iPhone in addition to an iPad, you might be able to develop a single application that runs on both devices, even if for deployment you plan on supporting only the iPad.  For example you could detect that you're on the iPhone and run only the functionality necessary to test multiplayer.  In my instance, this wasn't feasible, so I just went ahead and bought the 2nd iPad, but I mention it for completeness.

Finally, now that the third generation iPad has been released, you can probably find the first devices used for significantly less than retail.